# How to get the rss feeds into a string for WordPress 3.9.2

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am using the feedwordpress plugin. How does one get access to all the feeds content to put it into a string php variable before output? I figure it would be easier done by accessing the  post loop for the theme(which is "twentyfourteen") but I have been messing around with it for hours and nothing changes. Or maybe thats not the post loop "wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen". I am new to feedwordpress so still can't understand how to manipulate it from that end. I would be good to get the content into the hands of php to further filter it before output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the content of rss feeds have to go through either get_the_content or the_content() to post to the main area. Both of these functions are located here:wp-includes/post-template.php. get_the_cotent() so look for:

```
function get_the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false ) {...
```

and then where it says `return $output;` just above the '}' you can add $myvariable = $output.

The feeds are now in $myvariable so you can do whatever you want with it.